# Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

I have configured HTTP end point using Amazon API gateway.

Further I have added custom domain along with SSL certificate.

However on invoking api , I am getting Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine problem.

Now what is confusing that same SSL certificate works well for other Amazon API configured apis.

The API back end is Play Web Service and is being served through Nginx. 
From Cloud watch logs , I do not find much relevant information.

Comment: FYI: Someone posted a similar issue recently on the forums here, with a solution, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238651&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the issuer of your server certificate is not trusted by API Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

## Just For info.

Following analysis could be one of the reason for above issue.

The mentioned problem was being faced on following configuration.
Operating System :- UBUNTU 16.04 X64
NGINX :- 1.10.X

The issue was resolved on downgrading to following configuration.
Operating system to UBUNTU 14.04 x64 
NGINX to 1.4.6.

Though I am not sure , it appears to me that the problem with Nginx 1.10.x.

Answer (score 1):

Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine problem is a common error in the API Gateway private integration (VPC Link) and HTTP Integration.

General SSLEngine problem can be observed in following scenarios, when Integration returns :

- A certificate signed by issuers API gateway do not trust
- An expired certificate
- A self-signed certificate
- Certificate signing chain/chain of trust is missing the root certificate or one or more intermediate certificates
- Any other unrecognizable certificate-related exceptions

Read More here - https://cloudnamaste.com/general-sslengine-problem/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and then I contacted my SSL Support/Company and they added the intermediate certificate into the actual SSL certificate file using JavaKeyStore - which solved the issued